# How to connect VS Mac to a GitLab repo?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, visual-studio-mac

I'm starting a new project using Visual Studio 2017 Community for Mac.  I've already set up a GitLab repo for the project, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to connect VS Mac to the repo.

I tried looking in Microsoft's own documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-up-git-repository and found what, at first glance, looked like an answer.  However, when the documentation said to select "Publish in Version Control..." from the Version Control menu, well...

[image]

As you can see, there is no "Publish in Version Control..." command.  I've been doing Internet research to try to figure out what I missed, but I can't seem to be able to find that out.  How can I get VS Mac to connect to the GitLab repo, and what did I do wrong?

UPDATE: I have also taken a screenshot of the right-click menu on the solution.  Project names and code have been redacted.

[image]

Comment: Are you using VS for Mac for some particularly important reason? It's still rather rough around the edges, compared to a number of other options.

Comment: Yes.  I am using VS Mac because I want to do the development for this project in C# and don't know how to compile C# code in, for example, VS Code.

Comment: Fair enough. The VSCode setup is fairly well documented (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) if you're not particularly wed to VS for Mac itself.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't hurt to try using VS Code.  If worst comes to worst, I'd just end up using VS Mac again.  Or, actually, I might try VS for Windows, but only if I can't get VS Mac to work with this.

Comment: Is the Publish menu available if you right click the solution in the Solution window?

Comment: No, it is not.  I added a screenshot of that right-click menu to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Publish in version control** option is not meet your situation. It usually used for working at local repo as first (there is no remote repo related), and then connect the local repo to a remote repo.

For your situation, you can follow below steps to connect your remote (GitLab) repo in VS mac and manage git repo versions in VS:

#### 1.   Clone/checkout your Gitlab repo locally

VS -> Version control -> checkout -> connect to repository Tab -> select Type as Git -> input your gitlab repo URL -> specify the path/directory as you need -> checkout.

[image]

More details, you can refer [Checkout an existing repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-up-git-repository#checkout-an-existing-repository).

#### 2.   Manage versions in local git repo

You can open/edit the files of VS project in the local repo. After finishing working, you can save the changed files.

To commit and push the changes in VS: version control -> review solution and commit -> you can view the changed file(s) -> input commit message -> Commit. In the commit window, you can select **Push changes to remote repository after commit** option to push changes to GitLab. Or you can push changes to your GitLab repo in version control -> push changes option.

[image]

More details, you can refer [Reviewing and committing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/working-with-git#reviewing-and-committing).